# What actually calls logrotate in CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, logrotate

What actually calls `logrotate` in CentOS 6.3? I looked inside of `/etc/init.d` but nothing related to logrotate there. Also, nothing in the `crontab` for the `root` user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` is what you're looking for.